# Android Studio RC 4 ActionBar doesnt appear in preview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, preview, android-appcompat

Im creating a new project from 0 but when i see the preview doesnt show any actionBar , im just creating it from 0 i dont have any code,

a Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaeE1.png

here is my style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

And my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.jorwys.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But when i open a older project the preview does show me the actionbar so i think the problem is the new android studio; Thank you for the help. im sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

This Preview is only for your Layout Components. So if you wanna see there something you have to add it in your Layout Code. You could For Example add a sort of View you and take Acces of it in your Activity and change it as you like.

Comment: yeah but before i update the android studio , i can see it like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/mntyqlkz0ldxcoy/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-12-07%2016.42.11.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that was compiling with API 21 (Lollipop) so i change it to API 19 ( Kitkat) and also the appcompat library from: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+' to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20+'